# Get file path without the file

Tags: asp.net

On a web page, I need to allow users to input the path to a file - which will be stored in a database so I can subsequently display 'a list of documents that apply to this project'.

If I put an input type="file" on the page, it makes it easy for the user to browse to the document ... but, when the form is submitted, the document will be uploaded to the server. I don't want the document, I just want the path.

How would you provide the functionality to allow a user to browse to a file so that you could record the path to the file without actually uploading the file itself?

I just want to end up showing, on a web page, a list of files like:

\myserver\folder20\somefolder\somefile.doc

\myserver2\folder50\somefolder\somefile.doc

I need to give users an easy way to locate those files in the first place - without having to laboriously open Windows Explorer, find the file, and copy and paste the path.
A file upload control gives you access to the path - which is what I need - but I don't want the file uploaded.

Comment: Not at all, because you cannot get the full path from a file at the client due to security restrictions.

Comment: mover over , what will be then use of path, if it is being accessed on another machine

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam: I assume that OP wants to log the paths where the file is stored at each client. So if someone aks "who has this file and where is it" he can tell it. But that won't work as a server should not be interested in the directory structure of a client.

Comment: I don't want to 'get the full path from a file at the client' - I want users to enter the path to a file that they want to access later - when they are looking at a list of files belonging to a project. I just want to give them an easy way to navigate to the file without them having to open windows explorer, navigate to the file and cut and paste the path into a text box.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 'I assume that OP wants to log the paths where the file is stored at each client. So if someone aks "who has this file and where is it" he can tell it.'
No, that is not what I am after (thanks for your reply). I have modified the question to try to make cleared.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the file uploads path property is unreliable across browsers. For example in chrome it will come out as C:\fakepath\filename.txt

Comment: This is an IE only Intranet situation

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if this is what you want.

Assuming that you are selecting the file using input type="file" html control, you will be able to get the complete file path in jquery and pass that to your asp.net code behind using PageMethods (or ajax method of jquery). For this you would need to create a webmethod inside your aspx.cs class.

You can also get the machine name in javascript using any of the following lines of code

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"]
```

I was not able to test these as you have to enable Reverse DNS Lookup for your IIS. You need to search on the net for this.

So, the following steps you would need to do

1. Your file upload control should look something like this

   ```
   <input type="file" id="fileSel" />
   ```
2. put a scriptmanager tag, if you dont have one, in your html and set EnablePageMethods to true as

   ```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
   ```
3. Your javascript should look something like this.

   ```
   //in javascript

   $("document").ready(function () {
       $("#fileSel").change(function () {
           var val = $get("fileSel").value; // This will give you complete file path i.e. C:\...
           alert(val);
           PageMethods.SendForm(val, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);//Call to webmethod on server side

           //you can also use ajax method but I was not able to make this work

           //                $.ajax({
           //                    type: "POST",
           //                    //Page Name (in which the method should be called) and method name
           //                    url: "Default.aspx/SendForm",
           //                    // If you want to pass parameter or data to server side function you can try line
           //                    data: "{'fileName':'" + val + "'}",
           //                    //else If you don't want to pass any value to server side function leave the data to blank line below
           //                    //                    data: "{}",
           //                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           //                    dataType: "json",
           //                    success: function (msg) {
           //                        //Got the response from server and render to the client
           //                        alert(msg.d);
           //                    }
           //                });
       });
   });

   function OnSucceeded() {
       alert("success");
   }

   function OnFailed(error) {
       // Alert user of the error.
       alert("failure");
   }
   ```
4. The webmethod will be present inside the default.aspx.cs class as

   ```
   public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {

       [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
       public static void SendForm(string fileName)
       {
           //Do your stuff here
       }
   }
   ```

Hope you will be able to solve your problem using the above steps.

Regards,

Samar

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a go. I always thought you couldn't access the value of an input type = file. But, I guess you can access the value but could not change it?

Comment: I dont think the other way round is possible. I just searched some sites and questions on stackoverflow and they all say it is not possible but, now-a-days, you never know. I have not tried it from my end. You can research and let me also know if you find anything lead in this regard.